# Derivative and Series problem

Tags: derivatives

Hello everyone while playing with some simple maths I got into place I can't escape 
So following stament

$$ x^2 = x + x + ... + x $$

Where there are $x$ times $x+x+...+x$

If we take first derivative of both sides

We get

$\frac{dx^2}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dx} + ... + \frac{dx}{dx}$

$2x = 1 + ... + 1$ (there are $x$ times $1$ )

$2x = x$

$2=1$

How is this possible and why not possible to do so ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your very first equality is true if $\;x\;$ is an integer....try to do that with $\;x=\pi\;$ , say.

Answer (score 4):

It becomes more clear what went wrong if you write it in sigma notation:

$$x^2=\sum_{n=1}^xx$$

$$\frac d{dx}=\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^xx\stackrel?=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac d{dx}x=\sum_{n=1}^x1=x$$

But wait!  You forgot to differentiate the $x$ on the top as well!  And how *do* you differentiate the sum?  Well, be the limit definition:

$$\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^xx=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{x+h}(x+h)-\sum_{n=1}^xx}h$$

But wait again!  It doesn't make sense to have $\sum_{n=1}^{x+h}$ if $h$ is not an integer!  Thus, everything collapses and you can't use

$$x^2=\sum_{n=1}^xx$$

since $\sum$ only accepts natural numbers as it's bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much it is clear solution why is this not possible for non natural numbers Thanks again